# How to set new session id after getting access token in OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth, salesforce, access-token

I am developing an app for salesforce. For authentication I am using the web server flow. 
In salesforce OAuth implementation the session id is the same as access token. When I get the new access token (through refresh token method), what's the proper method to pass it to the client. Should I explicitly set the session ID to the new access token?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass it to the client"?

Comment: In our use case, the client makes some direct calls to salesforce (bypassing our web server) and needs to have the access token to directly connect to salesforce api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client can handle this by having some logic for handling a request to the Salesforce API which fails with an `Unauthorized` response.  When an `Unauthorized` response is received the client can ask your web server for a new access token / session id.

Alternatively you'd have to use WebSockets or some push technology to push the new access token to the client when the web server refreshes the token.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you included the `web` or `full` [scope](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm&language=en_US)s when requesting the OAuth 2.0 access token then it can be used interchangeably with a Session Id.

You put the access token into a `sid` cookie are redirect to the correct instance/pod.

Better yet, you can use the frontdoor.jsp to setup the required cookies. See [Using frontdoor.jsp to login to Salesforce UI and Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193348&language=en_US)